# VueCLI: v-text-field doesn't update value when v-date-picker changes

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a component where you can specify the input type, and it will automatically create the correct input. It will work with a `computed` property that returns an array with the fields you want.

One of the possible fields is a `v-date-picker`, hidden inside a menu, and whose value is displayed by a `v-text-field`

**InputForm COMPONENT**

```
<template>
  
  <!-- more input types here -->

  <v-menu 
    v-if="input.type == 'date'"
    v-model="menu"
    transition="scale-transition" 
    offset-y
    min-width="auto" 
    :close-on-content-click="false">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-text-field :key="keyHelper" :value='val' append-icon="mdi-calendar" :rules="rules" readonly filled hide-details dense v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-date-picker @click:date="menu = false" no-title v-model="val" :first-day-of-week="1" scrollable>
    </v-date-picker>
  </v-menu>

  <!-- more input types here -->

</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    input: Object,
    value: [Object, Array, String, Number, Boolean, Date, File],
    options: Array,
        rules: {
            type: Array,
            required: false,
            default: function () {return []}
        }
  },
  data(){
    return{
      keyHelper : false,
      menu : false,
    }
  },
    computed: {
        val: {
            get: function () {
                return this.value
            },
            set: function (v) {
                this.$emit('input', v)
            }
        }
    },
};
</script>
```

I have that component inside a dialog like this (`AuxInput` is just a row and 2 cols to set a label for an input):

```
<template>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" :max-width="options.width" :style="'z-index:' + options.zIndex" @keydown.esc="cancel">
      <v-card>
        <v-toolbar dark :color="options.color" dense flat>
          <v-toolbar-title class="white--text">{{ title }}</v-toolbar-title>
        </v-toolbar>
        <v-card-text class="pa-4">
            <v-form ref="formItem" v-model="valid">
                <template v-for="(input, index) in fields">
                    <AuxInput :title="input.title" >
                        <InputForm :rules="input.rules" :input="input" :value="input.value" @input="input.input" :options="input.options" />
                    </AuxInput>
                    <v-divider></v-divider>
                </template>
            </v-form>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions class="pt-0">
          <v-btn color="primary darken-1" text @click.native="send">Guardar</v-btn>
          <v-btn color="grey" text @click.native="cancel">Cancelar</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    components: {
        AuxInput: () => import("@/components/AuxInput.vue"),
        InputForm: () => import("./InputForm.vue"),
    },
    data(){
        return {
            rules: { req },
            type: null,
            menu: false,
            dialog: false,
            resolve: null,
            reject: null,
            valid: false,
            title: "",
            item: {},
            options: {
                color: '',
                width: 490,
                zIndex: 200
            }
        }
    },
    computed:{
        fields(){
            const setKey = (key, value) => {
                this.$set(this.item, key, value);
            }
            switch (this.type) {
                case 0:
                    return [
                        { title: 'Conversation date', type: 'date', value: this.item.date, input: (v) => setKey('date', v)}
                    ]
                // more types
                default:
                    return[]
            }
        },
    },
    methods:{
        open(type, item){
            // item will be null when creating a new item, or it will be an `Object`
            this.type = type
            Object.assign(this.item,item)
            this.options.color = 'info'
            this.title = 'New Conversation'
            this.dialog = true
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.resolve = resolve
                this.reject = reject
            })
        },
        send() {
            if (this.$refs.formItem.validate()){
                this.resolve(this.item)
                this.dialog = false
                this.item = {}
                this.type = null
            }
        },
        cancel() {
            this.resolve(false)
            this.dialog = false
            this.item = {}
            this.type = null
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I have another parent component where I do `this.$refs.dialog.open(type, item)`, and it pushes a new item into an array, or edits an old one, if the user fills the form correctly, and doesn't cancel.

Everything works fine when creating a new item (I change the `v-date-picker` value, and it's `v-text-field` updates).

The problem is when I try to edit an item, changing the `v-date-picker` does update the value internally, but it doesn't reflect on the `v-text-field` even though it's `value` is the same as the date picker's `v-model`, `val` is a computed property, and I use `$set` to set the value.

Gif showing the problem:
[image]

First time, when creating the item, the text field updates with the date picker. Second time, when editing the item, the text field doesn't update, but when saving, the date updates.